# Restructuring an array into a list of objects in a object Javascript/Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

My desired output is at the bottom of this post, I want to remove the array and put a list of objects inside an object.

I'm sharing my map function because i'm hopeful that there's a method inside there that can get my desired input and i'm just not doing it correctly.

If what i'm doing doesn't make sense i would love a better method of manipulating this data.

Starting Data(./updatepayloadTEMP.json)

```
{
 "outputparameters": [
    {
        "name": "0000x0000",
        "filepath": "D:\\Code\\ImageTiling\\6\\0000x0000.png"
    },
    {
        "name": "0000x0001",
        "filepath": "D:\\Code\\ImageTiling\\6\\0000x0001.png"
    },
    {
        "name": "0000x0002",
        "filepath": "D:\\Code\\ImageTiling\\6\\0000x0002.png"
    }
 ]
}
```

Variables

```
 let UpdatedTaskOutput = fs.readFileSync('./updatepayloadTEMP.json'); 
 let Updatedtaskoutputjson = JSON.parse(UpdatedTaskOutput); 
 var dynamictaskdetails = Updatedtaskoutputjson.outputparameters;
```

MAP func

```
   var taskparamscompiled = dynamictaskdetails.map(function (elem) {
   taskname = tasknamefromworkflowdef + elem.name;
   taskparms = taskparamsobj;
   return {
    [taskname]: taskparms,
   };
  });
```

What i'm currently getting for **taskparamscompiled**

```
 [
 {
   process0000x0000: {
    tr: 16,
    tc: 16,
    ofr: 16,
    ofc: 16,
    outfile: '"D:\\Code\\Process\\1"',
   },
  },
{
 process0000x0001: {
   tr: 16,
   tc: 16,
   ofr: 16,
   ofc: 16,
   outfile: '"D:\\Code\\Process\\1"',
  },
},
{
 process0000x0002: {
   tr: 16,
   tc: 16,
   ofr: 16,
   ofc: 16,
   outfile: '"D:\\Code\\Process\\1"',
 },
},
];
```

What I want

```
 {
   "process0000x0000": {
   "tr": 16,
   "tc": 16,
   "ofr": 16,
   "ofc": 16,
   "outfile": '"D:\\Code\\Process\\1"'
 },

    "process0000x0001": {
   "tr": 16,
   "tc": 16,
   "ofr": 16,
   "ofc": 16,
   "outfile": '"D:\\Code\\Process\\1"'
 },
 "process0000x0002": {
   "tr": 16,
   "tc": 16,
   "ofr": 16,
   "ofc": 16,
   "outfile": '"D:\\Code\\Process\\1"'
 },
}
```

I missed something, UPDATE:
I now need to get the filepath `( "filepath": "D:\\Code\\ImageTiling\\6\\0000x0000.png")` into the process object like this

```
process0000x0000: {
   filepath: "D:\\Code\\ImageTiling\\6\\0000x0000.png" 
    tr: 16,
    tc: 16,
    ofr: 16,
    ofc: 16,
    outfile: '"D:\\Code\\Process\\1"',
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.map()` will return an array.  You probably want to use `Array.prototype.reduce()`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

I think this gives you your desired output

```
const dynamictaskdetails = [
  {
    name: '0000x0000',
    filepath: 'D:\\Code\\ImageTiling\\6\\0000x0000.png'
  },
  {
    name: '0000x0001',
    filepath: 'D:\\Code\\ImageTiling\\6\\0000x0001.png'
  },
  {
    name: '0000x0002',
    filepath: 'D:\\Code\\ImageTiling\\6\\0000x0002.png'
  }
];

const taskparamsobj = {
  tr: 16,
  tc: 16,
  ofr: 16,
  ofc: 16,
  outfile: 'D:\\Code\\Process\\1'
};

const taskparamscompiled = dynamictaskdetails.reduce((accumulator, elem) => {
  const taskname = 'process' + elem.name;
  return {
    ...accumulator,
    [taskname]: taskparamsobj,
  };
}, {});

console.log(taskparamscompiled);
```

This resulted in the following output:

```
{
  process0000x0000: { tr: 16, tc: 16, ofr: 16, ofc: 16, outfile: 'D:\\Code\\Process\\1' },
  process0000x0001: { tr: 16, tc: 16, ofr: 16, ofc: 16, outfile: 'D:\\Code\\Process\\1' },
  process0000x0002: { tr: 16, tc: 16, ofr: 16, ofc: 16, outfile: 'D:\\Code\\Process\\1' }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i had a feeling i wasn't using Array.prototype.map() correctly

Comment: idk if i should reply or ask here but, What if i want to add the filepath from ./updatepayloadTEMP.json to the sub objects with the other properties?

Comment: last ditch effort, i made another post with my current status. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66230508/foreach-updating-record-with-last-record-from-dataset-for-every-record @josh-pospisil